# How to use left join with for json path in mssql?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

When I use `left join` with `for json path` I get an error:

> Property 'product_id' cannot be generated in JSON output due to a
> conflict with another column name or alias. Use different names and
> aliases for each column in SELECT list.

from this query:

```
select top 1
 1 as [foo.bar],
 p.*, cp.*
from product p
left JOIN company_product cp on cp.product_id = p.product_id
for json path
```

when I change from `for json path` to `for json auto` it's not throw error but the result is not output as expected:

```
 [{ "foo.bar": 1, "product_id": 751, ... "cp": [{ "product_id": 751, "company_id": 273, .. }]
```

and it's make another problem when I move `1 as [foo.bar]` to the end of the select:

```
select top 1
     p.*, cp.*,
     1 as [foo.bar]
    from product p
    left JOIN company_product cp on cp.product_id = p.product_id
    for json auto
```

The `foo.bar` is **inside** `cp` object. and it's not as expected:

```
 [{ "product_id": 751, ... "cp": [{ "product_id": 751, "company_id": 273, "foo.bar": 1, ..}]
```

Instead should be:

```
  [{ "product_id": 751, ... "cp": [{ "product_id": 751, "company_id": 273, ..}], "foo.bar": 1, ..}]
```

So I have those problems when I use `for json auto`. any idea if there is a way to use `left join` with `for path` or solve this issues that `for auto` makes?

Comment: What is the expected output if there are multiple rows for one `product_id` in the `company_product` table?

Comment: I think it should be an array. not an object. it's easier that way.

Comment: `FOR JSON PATH` can't have duplicate column names. If you specify each column and its graph then it will work. For example `cp.product_id AS [cp.product_id]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), when *...you specify the AUTO option, the format of the JSON output is automatically determined based on the order of columns in the SELECT list and their source tables...* and you *...can't change this format*. So, a possible option is to use a subquery:

Tables:

```
SELECT *
INTO product
FROM (VALUES (751)) v (product_id)
SELECT *
INTO company_product
FROM (VALUES (751, 273), (751, 274)) v (product_id, company_id)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT p.*, cp.*
FROM (
   SELECT *, 1 as [foo.bar]
   FROM product 
) p
LEFT JOIN company_product cp on cp.product_id = p.product_id
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Result:

```
[
   {
      "product_id":751,
      "foo.bar":1,
      "cp":[
         {"product_id":751, "company_id":273},
         {"product_id":751, "company_id":274}
      ]
   }
]
```